# ExtJs Neptune theme

Tags: extjs, themes, extjs4.2

I'm trying to change default theme in ExtJs 4.2 to Neptune custom theme. How to make it for debugging?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you setting up your project using Sencha Cmd?

Comment: Yes I use it for deploying, but I need change theme for debugging.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must have the following files and folders:

1. extjs/**ext-all.js**
2. extjs/**ext-theme-neptune.js**
3. extjs/resources/css/**ext-all-neptune.css**
4. extjs/resources/ext-theme-neptune/**ext-theme-neptune-all.css**
5. extjs/resources/ext-theme-neptune/**images/*.***

And your code as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-custom.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if you only have the ext-all-neptune and the ext-theme-neptune folder? do you have to preserve the whole directory structure of extjs to be able to use it?

Comment: You need only files listed in post, all other may be deleted. File ext-all-neptune.css and folder ext-theme-neptune enough for neptune style.

Answer (score 5):

To change to the neptune theme modify `line 33` of your `sencha.cfg` file located in **.sencha/app/sencha.cfg** to

`app.theme=ext-theme-neptune`

After doing this run `sencha app refresh` in your terminal or cammand line

Comment: "After doing this run sencha app refresh in your terminal or cammand line" - this is for deploying my application?

Comment: This will also change your theme while developing.

Answer (score 3):

I did as @ccerville said but finished with a

```
 sencha app build
```

which did some magic to the bootstrap.css and allowed debugging page to use neptune.   The 'refresh' didn't seem to make a difference, whereas the build modifies bootstrap.css which is what the 'debug' index.html uses.

Some more info available here : http://senchado.blogspot.ca/2013/03/extjs-42-app-with-custom-neptune-based.html

Answer (score -1):

in app.json change line 31 where "theme" define.
change it "theme": "ext-theme-neptune"

After doing this run sencha app build in your terminal or cammand line